# ReactJS: Is it safe to use a conditional in the event of an undefined props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I have an Immutable.Map with a couple of key value pairs.

```
Object {1: -200, 2: 13540}

<Component
    items={this.props.items.get(key) || 0}
/>
```

The key may or may not exist in the map. In the case that it doesn't exist I just want to pass in zero to the component. It is a required props.

Is the conditional in there safe? What is a better approach if it's not safe?

Answer (score 1):

A conditional is safe, but the way you have is ambiguous - you are likely going to get the result of the boolean expression, not the actual value.

I would do it like this to be explicit:

```
let val = this.props.items.get(key);
items={val ? val : 0}
```

This explicitly returns either `val` or `0`, rather than the result of the boolean expression `val || 0`.

Comment: This is a codesmell(meaning something else is wrong and this is only a symptom.) Yes initialize in the case of undefined, but this doesn't cover all edge cases and you probably should solve this in the store/source of truth.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it's not going to compile just yet without some heavy modification, but **yes** you can certainly be doing that sort of thing.

The key is that Immutable.js does not throw an error on a missing key but returns the JS value `undefined` which is falsy, so `undefined || 0` evaluates to `0` via the very-type-lax "if this first thing is truthy, return whatever it is, otherwise return whatever that second thing" behavior of `||`.